# Gaussian fit to histogram is flat

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I created a python script that plots a row of data from a file then fits it with a gaussian curve. The red step histogram is a set of data whose average I would like to compare to a real data value, which is the blue dashed line. The Gaussian fit is barely visible at the bottom of the graph, it is a dashed green line. I can't find out why the fit is flat instead of a curve as the mean and sigma that are calculated are correct; they are the title of the graph.

[image: Graph]

## My Source Code

```
    from scipy.stats import norm
    import scipy, pylab
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    df = numpy.loadtxt('CR_count_TAL=0.10472.dat',dtype='str')

    for num in range(1):
        nu=df[num].astype('float')
        data = nu[1]
        mc=df[2:numpy.size(nu)]
        #plot the MC distribution
        #hist(nu[2:size(nu)],bins=100,color='r',range=(100,500),histtype='step')

        #plot the dataline
        axvline(data,color='b',linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
        #fit a gaussian
        #(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(nu)
        plt.hist(nu[2:size(nu)],bins=100,color='r',range=(100,500),histtype='step')
        y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
        l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'g', linewidth = 2, linestyle='--')

        plt.title(r'$\ \mu=%.3f,\ \sigma=%.3f$' %(mu, sigma))
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Please see a full working example here, adapted from your code

```
import numpy as np                                                                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                    
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab                                                     

mu = 100                                                                           
sigma = 20                                                                         
n_sample = 3000                                                                    

data = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n_sample)                                       

# plot the data                                                               
_, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=100, color='r', range=(50, 150),
                      histtype='step', normed=True)                                                                                       
# plot the gaussian PDF                                                              
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)                                                  
plt.plot(bins, y, 'g', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')                                
plt.axvline(mu, color='b', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')                                                                                        
plt.title(r'$\ \mu=%.3f,\ \sigma=%.3f$' % (mu, sigma))                             
plt.show()
```

It gives this picture

[image]

The issue is that your `y` is a probability distribution that normalizes to 1 but your histogram is not. Thus there are two ways to deal with it:

- scale the PDF
- normalized the histogram

The normalization is basically the area under the histogram curve, which can be calculated from a numerical integration. It is affected by

- number of samples
- bin size

Note that `plt.hist` can do this for you by passing in the `normed=True` option.

Comment: I made this correction except now I get no Gaussian fit at all

Comment: @nos `normed` is deprecated - would `density=True` do the exact same job?